# Associated constants in condition of constant ìf`-expression

Tags: rust, associated-const

I am trying to use associated constants as a condition in an `if`-expression to initialize another constant. I think that this should work, as I can use the associated constants directly to initialize some other constant, so it is applicable in a const context and the if expression does not depend on any other values.

```
trait C {
    const c: i32;
}

trait StaticAssert<T1: C, T2: C> {
    const canUseAssociatedConst: i32 = T1::c;
    const canCompareAssociatedConst: bool = T1::c == T2::c;

    const check: i32 = if T1::c == T2::c { 1 } else { 0 };
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error:

```
error[E0019]: constant contains unimplemented expression type
 --> src/lib.rs:9:24
  |
9 |     const check: i32 = if T1::c == T2::c { 1 } else { 0 };
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am not sure what the compiler wants to tell me. I've added `i32` suffixes to enforce that the literals are actually `i32` values to prevent any issues from different types in the branches, but this did not help either.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2342

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, `if` and others are not (yet) supported in `const` contexts.

However, often you can acchieve a similar effect along the lines of the following:

```
trait C {
    const c: i32;        
}

trait StaticAssert<T1:C, T2:C> {
    const canUseAssociatedConst: i32 = T1::c;
    const canCompareAssociatedConst: bool = T1::c == T2::c;

    const check: i32 = (T1::c == T2::c) as i32;
}
```

Comment: A `const fn` with an if-expression gives a better error message: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=156bb6f19dc28b5f554c2df2d24fcd67. However, functions without ifs are not very usefull... The class of functions that can be represented without conditions is rather small.

Comment: @Jens A slightly more general hack is to use `[expr1, expr2][condition as usize]` to select between two const expressions based on a condition.